# How does `-rpcconnect` option work?

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor

Its mentioned that `-rpcconnect` can be used to send commands to a remote Bitcoin Core node: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bitcoin-cli.cpp#L70

I am testing this option by using the format mentioned here: https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line/blob/master/14_1_Verifying_Your_Tor_Setup.md

```
torify bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=vazr3k6bgnfafmdpcmbegoe5ju5kqyz4tk7hhntgaqscam2qupdtk2yd.onion -rpcport=1309 -rpcpassword=password3 getblockchaininfo
```

If I use the onion address for my node returned in `getnetworkinfo`, I get the below error:

```
error: Could not connect to the server vazr3k6bgnfafmdpcmbegoe5ju5kqyz4tk7hhntgaqscam2qupdtk2yd.onion:1309 (error code 1 - "EOF reached")
```

and If I use the onion address saved in */var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/hostname*, I get this error:

```
error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword
```

I am assuming connection works fine in second error but issues with rpc credentials. Below are contents of `bitcoin.conf`:

```
testnet=1
prune=1000

server=1

listen=1
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
torcontrol=127.0.0.1:9051
debug=tor

test.rpcport=18332

test.rpcuser=user3
test.rpcpassword=password3
```

Comment: The onion address exposed through `getnetworkinfo` is irrelevant. Bitcoin Core is only automatically setting up an onion service for P2P communication, not RPC.

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming it can be used for both.

Comment: Your command doesn't contain `-rpcuser`.

Comment: @AndrewChow That resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

`-rpcuser` was missing in the command. Also, the onion address exposed through `getnetworkinfo` is irrelevant. Bitcoin Core is only automatically setting up an onion service for P2P communication, not RPC.

Below command works fine:

```
torify bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=vazr3k6bgnfafmdpcmbegoe5ju5kqyz4tk7hhntgaqscam2qupdtk2yd.onion -rpcport=1309 -rpcuser=user3 -rpcpassword=password3 getblockchaininfo
```